# remove empty sub arrays value using array_filter

Tags: php, arrays, array-filter

I add arrays with sub arrays value data into `mysql` database like this:

```
{"2":[
{"title":"english title","link":"english url"},
{"title":"","link":""}],
"1":[
{"title":"french title","link":"french url"},
{"title":"","link":""}]}
```

I try to remove `empty` sub array value using `array_filter` and `array_map` like this:

```
var_dump(array_filter(array_map('array_filter', $links)));
```

now, when i check using `var_dump` I see this result and `array_filter` and `array_map` can not remove empty value:

```
array(2) {
  [2]=>
  array(3) {
    [0]=>
    array(2) {
      ["title"]=>
      string(13) "english title"
      ["link"]=>
      string(11) "english url"
    }
    [1]=>
    array(2) {
      ["title"]=>
      string(0) ""
      ["link"]=>
      string(0) ""
    }
  }
  [1]=>
  array(3) {
    [0]=>
    array(2) {
      ["title"]=>
      string(12) "french title"
      ["link"]=>
      string(10) "french url"
    }
    [1]=>
    array(2) {
      ["title"]=>
      string(0) ""
      ["link"]=>
      string(0) ""
    }
  }
}
```

in action, how do can i remove `empty` sub arrays value ?!

**UPDATE**: i need to this result:

```
Array
(
    [2] => Array
        (
            [0] => Array
                (
                    [title] => english title
                    [link] => english url
                )

        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [0] => Array
                (
                    [title] => french title
                    [link] => french url
                )
        )

)
```

Comment: What is your expected output?

Comment: If you thought that the object or array resulting from JSON-decoding `{"title":"","link":""}` would be considered “empty” by PHP … then you are wrong.

Comment: @Nick: i need to remove empty value from array like this:`Array([2] => Array(   [0] => Array([title] => english title [link] => english url)) [1] => Array([0] => Array(  [title] => french title [link] => french url )))`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem is that the items you are trying to filter are not empty (`empty($links[2][1]) === false`), they are a two element array, so `array_filter` will not remove them. Instead you need to check that both elements are blank. For example, using [`array_walk`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-walk):

```
array_walk($links, function (&$array) { 
    $array = array_filter($array, function ($obj) {
        return $obj['title'] != '' || $obj['link'] != '';
    });
});

print_r($links);
```

Output:

```
Array
(
    [2] => Array
        (
            [0] => Array
                (
                    [title] => english title
                    [link] => english url
                )
        )
    [1] => Array
        (
            [0] => Array
                (
                    [title] => french title
                    [link] => french url
                )
        )
)
```

[Demo on 3v4l.org](https://3v4l.org/catFY)